# Compute average through different days in loop pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
Date    Daily Risk Score
0   2020-06-26  6.0
1   2020-06-27  6.0
2   2020-06-28  6.0
3   2020-06-29  6.0
4   2020-06-30  6.0
5   2020-07-01  6.0
6   2020-07-02  6.0
7   2020-07-03  6.0
8   2020-07-04  6.0
9   2020-07-05  6.0
10  2020-07-06  6.0
11  2020-07-07  6.0
12  2020-07-08  6.0
13  2020-07-09  6.0
14  2020-06-26  6.0
15  2020-06-27  6.0
16  2020-06-28  6.0
17  2020-06-29  6.0
18  2020-06-30  6.0
19  2020-07-01  6.0
20  2020-07-02  6.0
21  2020-07-03  6.0
22  2020-07-04  6.0
23  2020-07-05  6.0
24  2020-07-06  6.0
25  2020-07-07  6.0
26  2020-07-08  6.0
27  2020-07-09  6.0
28  2020-06-26  1.0
29  2020-06-27  1.0
```

The actual dataframe is something like 50k entries. I want to then take the mean of all the Daily Risk Scores on every date. Then I would like to store each of the 14 new mean values in a new column called 'means', where there are 14 values corresponding to the date they were calculated for.

I tried to do this:

```
df2['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) 
dates=pd.date_range(today, (today+dt.timedelta()))
for i in dates:
    df2=df2[df2['Date']==i]
    df2['means']=df2['Daily Risk Score'].mean()
```

But this only computes the mean for the very first day and then stops the loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain `Then I would like to store each of the 14 new mean values in a new column called 'means', where there are 14 values corresponding to the date they were calculated for.`. Why only `14` values?

Comment: I only need 14 total new values. I want my script to calculate the mean for all days that are 2020-06-26, and then for all days that are 2020-06-27, and so forth. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, i'm wondering whats the logic in considering only the 14 new values.  Consider adding the expected output.

Comment: you can use `df2.groupby('Date').agg({'Daily Risk Score': mean})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
mean_df = df.groupby("Date").mean().reset_index()
mean_df.columns = ["Date", "ScoreMean"]
#          Date     means
#0   2020-06-26  4.333333
#1   2020-06-27  4.333333
#2   2020-06-28  6.000000
#3   2020-06-29  6.000000
#4   2020-06-30  6.000000
#5   2020-07-01  6.000000
#6   2020-07-02  6.000000
#7   2020-07-03  6.000000
#8   2020-07-04  6.000000
#9   2020-07-05  6.000000
#10  2020-07-06  6.000000
#11  2020-07-07  6.000000
#12  2020-07-08  6.000000
#13  2020-07-09  6.000000

result = pd.merge(df, mean_df, on="Date")
#          Date  DailyRiskScore     means
#0   2020-06-26             6.0  4.333333
#1   2020-06-26             6.0  4.333333
#2   2020-06-26             1.0  4.333333
#3   2020-06-27             6.0  4.333333
#4   2020-06-27             6.0  4.333333
#5   2020-06-27             1.0  4.333333
#6   2020-06-28             6.0  6.000000
#7   2020-06-28             6.0  6.000000
#8   2020-06-29             6.0  6.000000
#9   2020-06-29             6.0  6.000000
#10  2020-06-30             6.0  6.000000
#11  2020-06-30             6.0  6.000000
#12  2020-07-01             6.0  6.000000
#13  2020-07-01             6.0  6.000000
#14  2020-07-02             6.0  6.000000
#15  2020-07-02             6.0  6.000000
#16  2020-07-03             6.0  6.000000
#17  2020-07-03             6.0  6.000000
#18  2020-07-04             6.0  6.000000
#19  2020-07-04             6.0  6.000000
#20  2020-07-05             6.0  6.000000
#21  2020-07-05             6.0  6.000000
#22  2020-07-06             6.0  6.000000
#23  2020-07-06             6.0  6.000000
#24  2020-07-07             6.0  6.000000
#25  2020-07-07             6.0  6.000000
#26  2020-07-08             6.0  6.000000
#27  2020-07-08             6.0  6.000000
#28  2020-07-09             6.0  6.000000
```

Comment: I think this is doing what I want. Is there a good way to check, since the dataframe is about 50k entries?

Comment: First, make sure that `mean_df` size is equal to the number of unique dates you have which is 14 I think. Then, you can check random rows at `result` and make sure everything is as expected.

Comment: Did I answer you question?